# how to add java.lang.Integer to PieChart.Data

Tags: javafx

I want to show javaRDD data in javafx piechart. while i am passing data to PieChart.Data  it is accepting only double type as measure. how to make any number can be acceptable.

my code snippet

```
int cIndex = 0;
int mIndex = 1;

ObservableList<PieChart.Data> pieChartData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    tableMap.collect().forEach((Row row)->{
            if(row.get(cIndex)!= null && row.get(mIndex) != null){
                    pieChartData.add(new PieChart.Data(row.getString(cIndex), (double) row.get(mIndex)));
        }
    });
```

Comment: I´m not sure what the question is. 

The `PieChart.Data`'s constructor accepts only a double, and in the code the row's number data is casted to a double, so this is what it is, except of course if the row doesn't return a primitive but an object. If it does a primitive the `if` statement doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

A quick browse in the [JavaDoc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/api/java/index.html) reveals a method [`getDouble(int)`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Row.html#getDouble(int)).

Edit: given that javaRDD offers streaming functions, I'd expect the code to use that instead of first collecting everything into an array.

```
tableMap.filter(r -> !r.isNullAt(cIndex) && !r.isNullAt(mIndex))
        .map(r -> new PieChart.Data(r.getString(cIndex), r.getDouble(mIndex)))
        .forEach(pieChartData::add);
```